# Seaborn facetgrid bubbleplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, bubble-chart, facet-grid

I have a seaborn facetgrid, with each cell being a scatterplot.

I am trying to get the point sizes to vary proportional to group size - bubbleplot.

How can I do this?

Example data

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(data= 
{'column_var':['group 1','group 1','group 2','group 2'],
 'x_var':[1,2,4,5],
 'y_var':[2,4,3,6],
 'size':[10,20,40,80],})
```

current code - produces scatterplot.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="column_var",col_wrap=3,sharex=False, sharey=True)
g = (g.map(sns.scatterplot,"x_var", "y_var").add_legend())
```

I want to tweak this so that each point size is proportionate to the 'size' variable.

attempt 1

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="column_var",size='size',col_wrap=3,sharex=False, sharey=True)
g = (g.map(sns.scatterplot,"x_var", "y_var").add_legend())
```

attempt 2:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(agg_rn_df, col="mkt_zap",col_wrap=3,sharex=False, sharey=True)
g = (g.map(sns.scatterplot,"rn_bin", "flag_reserved",size='size').add_legend())
```

Can this be done easily using facetgrid, or is using matplotlib subplots a better solution?

Comment: I've added an example dataframe.

Comment: `g = g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, "x_var", "y_var", size="size")` should work. The legend is pretty useless in that case though. Matplotlib subplots give you a much higher degree of customizability, at the expense of more codelines needed.

Comment: This works perfectly.